# Convert C++ to MIPS assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, mips

This code is about to find maximum element from an array i want to convert this code into MIPS assembly code can anyone help me...Or just tell me how to initialize an array in MIPS.

```
void max_array()
{
    int a[10]={2,3,421,4,32,4,3,1,4,5},max;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i];
    }
    max=a[0];
    for(int j=1;j<9;j++)
    {
        if (max<a[j])
        {
             max=a[j];
        }
    }
    return max;

 }
```

Comment: Can you not just compiler it with a MIPS C compiler and look at the output? In GCC you can get the assembly output using `-S`

Comment: @PeterAlexander -S will produce x86 assembly  I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example

```
        .data
array1:     .space  12              #  declare 12 bytes of storage to hold array of 3 integers
        .text
__start:    la  $t0, array1     #  load base address of array into register $t0
        li  $t1, 5                  #  $t1 = 5   ("load immediate")
        sw $t1, ($t0)                #  first array element set to 5; indirect addressing
        li $t1, 13                  #   $t1 = 13
        sw $t1, 4($t0)           #  second array element set to 13
        li $t1, -7                  #   $t1 = -7
        sw $t1, 8($t0)           #  third array element set to -7
        done
```

Comment: Just wondering:  there a reason the array can't be declared in the data section and just pointed to?  It's effectively constant in the C code anyway...

Comment: You're right. I believe you can also do `array1: .word '2', '3', '421'` etc

Answer (score 3):

```
    .data   # variable decleration follow this line

array1: .word   2, 3, 421, 4, 32, 4, 3, 1, 4, 5 #10 element array is declared
max:    .word   2

la  $t0, array1         #load base address of array1
main:                       #indicated the start of the code
#to access an array element ($t0), 4($t0), 8($t0)..........
```

Comment: And 421 stored in a byte is...?

Comment: yea that would be a problem, so change it to WORD

Answer (score 0):

convert to mips

```
addi $t1, $0, 99 
addi $t4, $0, 9 
add $t3, $t2, $t1 
sub $t3, $t3, $t4

loop: lw $s1, 0($t2)
lw $s2, 0($t3) 
slt $s3, $s1, $s2 
beq $s3, $0, label1 
sub $s4, $s2, $s1 
sw $s4,0($t3) 
j label2

label1: 
sub $s4, $s1, $s2 
sw $s4,0($t3)

label2: 
addi $t2, $t2, 4 
addi $t3, $t3, 4 
subi $t1, $t1,1 
beq $t1, $0, loop
```

Comment: When posting some code in your answer, please `select it as a block` and then press `{}` on the toolbar of editor-form. This will format the code appropriately. Or remember that lines should be indented by 4 spaces to appear as non-proportional source code.