# How can I initialize an array in MIPS?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538659/convert-c-to-mips-assembly), I inquired about converting the MAX_ARRAY() function into MIPS. I have completed that task. Now, I wish to initialize an array in my program. How might I achieve this?

```
       addi  $t1,$zero, 0   # initialize index i to 0
 loop: add   $t1,$t1,1         # increment index i by 1
       beq   $t1,$s2,done   # if all elements examined, quit
       add   $t2,$t1,$t1    # compute 2i in $t2
       add   $t2,$t2,$t2    # compute 4i in $t2 
       add   $t2,$t2,$s1    # form address of A[i] in $t2 
       lw    $t3,0($t2) # load value of A[i] into $t3
       slt   $t4,$t0,$t3    # maximum < A[i]?
       beq   $t4,$zero,loop # if not, repeat with no change
       addi  $t0,$t3,0         # if so, A[i] is the new maximum 
       j     loop       # change completed; now repeat
 done:
```

Comment: The answers to the question you linked to show that - both dynamically and statically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs354-2/onyourown/arrays.html 
Hope this helps you... Wasn't able to find more appropriate answer

Comment: That page has been moved to here: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~smoler/cs354/onyourown/arrays.html