# MIPS Data Directives

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm new in MIPS and trying to teach myself using [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CD8QFjAA&url=http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~shambhu/cse34113/handouts/britton-mips-tutorial.pdf&ei=w5f0UYLgJJC08QSl8YHQBg&usg=AFQjCNG6BVXpFK5nMjqwbFJviy9XdSUI6g&sig2=z0KJQBDGPftOg4TyHHrhqw&bvm=bv.49784469,d.eWU) book. I'm trying to learn data directive and what are the difference between these three :

```
list:   .word 0:3
list:   .word 3
list:   .word
```

But I didn't find any clear document/reference.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list:   .word 0:3
```

Will reserve 3 words and set each to the value `0`. This would be similar to:

```
int list[3] = {0, 0, 0};
```

Or

```
list:   .space 12
```

(In which case, the value is implicitly 0).

The 0 in '0:3' could have very well be any other value. For example:

```
list:   .word 'X':3
# or
list:   .word 88:3
```

When the number of elements is missing, it's simply the value of the word

```
list:   .word 3
```

Which is similar to

```
int list = 3;
```

The last one,

```
list:   .word
```

Will likely cause assemblers to complain for the missing operand.

Comment: Thank You and Perfect Answer. But one more question: list:   .word 0:3 is a Dynamic memory allocation or Static? How about stack pointer ($sp)?

Comment: @Hooman That's static. It's all static in fact. The .data or .rdata are used mainly for static data setup when your program starts up. Just like the C's `static` keyword when outside of any function. Dynamic memory, typically via `new` or `malloc()` are typically allocated via a system call (Look up `syscall`). Memory allocated on the stack are your typical C automatic variables. For example `void foo() { int x; }` here x is an automatic variable that will be allocated on the stack.