# Initializing .space in memory for assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

How do I initialize this `.space` to zeroes? I want every single bit to be `0`.

My code subroutine:

```
.data
.align 2
memspace: .space 256
.text
la   $t7, memspace
move $t2, $zero
add  $t2, $t2, 64         # should this be 256 / 4? confused
loop:
    beq  $t2, $zero, done
    sw   $t0, ($t7)
    addi $t7, $t7,   4
    addi $t2, $t2,   -1
    j loop
done:
    jr $ra
```

I definitely am doing something wrong as when I use `xspim` and look under my data segment I don't see the reserved space of `256`. I feel like my `$t` registers don't do anything to the actual memory locations. I'm really confused right now. Should I be using stack pointers?

Comment: Shouldn't you store `$zero` instead of `$t0`?

Comment: Why not just `memspace: .word 0:64`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904886/mips-data-directives

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
memspace: .space 0:256
```

This will initialize everything to 0, although i believe 0 is the default.
See [How to initialise a huge array in MIPS assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771569/how-to-initialise-a-huge-array-in-mips-assembly/49642036#49642036)